# Roblox Look at mouse camera rotation problem

Tags: lua, camera, roblox

The devforum was no help so I'm asking it here.

Im trying to make a Five Nights At Freddys game and I’m making the custom camera script, but its not facing the correct direction. Why is this happening?

Video:
https://doy2mn9upadnk.cloudfront.net/uploads/default/original/4X/0/2/4/024cca4de534dcfc084a944d3c2a13abf5382e0c.mp4

Code

---

```
RunService.RenderStepped:Connect(function()
    if PlayerCharacter:WaitForChild("Player"):WaitForChild("isNightGuard").Value and not game.ReplicatedStorage:FindFirstChild("GameData"):FindFirstChild("inCams").Value then
        Mouse.TargetFilter = game.Workspace.NightguardPosition
        CurrentCamera.CFrame = CFrame.new(game.Workspace.NightguardPosition.CFrame.Position)
        CurrentCamera.CFrame = CFrame.new(CurrentCamera.CFrame.Position, Mouse.UnitRay.Direction * 10)
    end
end)
```

The NightguardPosition part is in the correct position and orientation.
I’ve tried many variations of the camera script but they all have the same result, please help?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that for the `CFrame.new(Vector3: position, Vector3: lookAt)` constructor, the second `Vector3` is what the `CFrame` will point at in world-space and is not a direction vector, unless `position` is (0, 0, 0), the origin. To fix the issue, you must add `NightguardPosition.Position` to the where the mouse is pointing in the world since that unit ray of the mouse like an offset when having to set `lookAt`.
Modified code with some comments (changes made to RenderStepped are suggestions and do not need to be built around!):

```
CurrentCamera.CameraSubject = workspace.NightguardPosition --// The CameraSubject is the LocalPlayer's Humanoid by default, causing some funky movements. Make sure to revert this
--// when cameras are exited.

--// Small performance improvement, unless this is changed elsewhere. Either way, it is best to only set when necessary and not in a looping behavior.
Mouse.TargetFilter = game.Workspace.NightguardPosition
local nightGuardPos = workspace.NightguardPosition.Position

RunService.RenderStepped:Connect(function()
    --// CurrentCamera.CFrame = CFrame.new(game.Workspace.NightguardPosition.CFrame.Position)
    --// Can be removed as this is the same as getting the Position of NightguardPosition
    
    CurrentCamera.CFrame = CFrame.new(nightGuardPos, nightGuardPos + Mouse.UnitRay.Direction * 10)
end)
```